# Making only some columns editable on streamlit-aggrid?

Tags: ag-grid, streamlit

I'm new to streamlit-aggrid.
I have a CSV file I want to load to a dynamic table and allow editions to only some of the columns.
I saw this example:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
grid_return = AgGrid(df, editable=True)
new_df = grid_return['data']
```

So I've followed it, but let's say that instead of editable=True, that allows both col1 and col2 values to be modified, I want to allow modifications on one of them (not important which one).

How can I do that please?
Thanks!

I tried to pass a columns subset into the editable args but it is only accepting boolean values.

Comment: Could you tell us why you are doing this? What is your use case?

Comment: Sure. I want to update a CSV that will contain some changeable parameters in addition to some constant ones.
For example I would wish the ID field to be protected but names can change so I want that to be editable etc.